# Function gets called twice

Tags: jquery, html

I have a structure of 3 div's held inside another div. On click of any of these divs i am running a Jquery function.

Currently I have fixed an Alert within the jQuery. My problem is that the Alert gets triggered twice which probably means the function gets called twice. This is not the desired output.

Here a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ksnRA/)

HTML

```
<div id="prompt_network_box" class="network_deck_on">
    <div id="address_header" class="address_headers_on">CHOOSE A NETWORK YOU ARE A MEMBER OF</div>
    <div class="wizzard_networks_container" id="wizzard_networks_container">
        <div id="network_picker,1,Blogger" class="wizzard_network_holder">
            <img src="media/images/social/Blogger.png" width="57" height="57" alt="Blogger">
        </div>
        <div id="network_picker,2,Art" class="wizzard_network_holder">
            <img src="media/images/social/ART.png" width="57" height="57" alt="Art">
        </div>
        <div id="network_picker,3,Tech" class="wizzard_network_holder">
            <img src="media/images/social/tech.png" width="57" height="57" alt="digg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('div').on('click', '[id^=network_picker]', function (e) {
    alert("YOU CLICKED IT!")
});
```

Comment: You should start by fixing your invalid markup. IDs must be unique and not have `,` in them.

Comment: your handler executes for both #wizzard_networks_container and #prompt_network_box

Comment: @boz I'll admit they're ugly, but they are completely valid in HTML5 as there are no duplicates, and they don't contain spaces.

Comment: @boz There is are reason for using the id's the way they are. ;-)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you learn something new every day - I thought commas were still illegal characters in ids/class names!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you are atttaching the delegate to EVERY `div` element in the page. The `network_picker...` elements have two containing divs, so you the function is called twice.

Instead use a single parent for the delegate, and use the classes to filter the event targets, like this:

```
$('#wizzard_networks_container').on('click', '.wizzard_network_holder', function (e) {
    alert("YOU CLICKED IT!")
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksnRA/2/)

I'd also suggest changing the `id` attributes on the `.wizzard_network_holder` divs as they're not very semantic.

Answer (score 2):

Add this `e.stopPropagation()`.

```
$('div').on('click', '[id^=network_picker]', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("YOU CLICKED IT!")
});
```

And you seriously should use better ids. No commas or spaces and they should be unique!

Comment: While this may work, attaching a click event to every single `div` element on the page is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
$('div[id^=network_picker]').on('click', function () {

    alert("YOU CLICKED IT!")

});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/ksnRA/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, the `on` function will handle that. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ksnRA/6/

Comment: no, the version you have will only work for DOM elements available on load. The OPs original is a delegate handler for both elements present on load and those added after. Check the `on()` entry in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Here my suggestion:

HTML:

```
<div id="prompt_network_box" class="network_deck_on">
<div id="address_header" class="address_headers_on">CHOOSE A NETWORK YOU ARE A MEMBER OF</div>
<div class="wizzard_networks_container" id="wizzard_networks_container">
    <div data-id="1" data-name="Blogger" class="wizzard_network_holder, network_picker">
        <img src="media/images/social/Blogger.png" width="57" height="57" alt="Blogger">
    </div>
    <div data-id="2" data-name="Art" class="wizzard_network_holder, network_picker">
        <img src="media/images/social/ART.png" width="57" height="57" alt="Art">
    </div>
    <div data-id="3" data-name="Tech" class="wizzard_network_holder, network_picker">
        <img src="media/images/social/tech.png" width="57" height="57" alt="digg">
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.network_picker').on('click', function (e) {
    alert("YOU CLICKED IT!");
    alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

I changed your ids to data-attributes and moved the "network_picker" to classes. You can access the data-id and data-name as shown in the JQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you write `$('div')` every div is registered to handle the click event, thus it is called multiple times for nested div elements

You should use a more distinct selector, e.g. `$('div.wizzard_networks_container')`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.wizzard_networks_container').on('click', '[id^=network_picker]', function (e) {
    alert("YOU CLICKED IT!")
});
```